# Player Object moving incorrectly in simple physics simulation GMS

Tags: game-physics, game-maker

I've created a very simple game for simulating rolling a ball in a "ball-maze" style game in Gamemaker Studio. It consists solely of a player object and walls that it cannot move through.

The player object has a vert-speed and a horiz-speed that are increased/decreased when you press the movement keys, and then it's position is shifted by those speeds once per step (until it hits a wall). I've also added basic deceleration when no buttons are being pressed.

It mostly works, but I have a very specific bug. When moving very quickly and +positively (**Right** or **Down**; **S** or **D** in terms of **WASD**) along the x or y axis, if I provide input in the opposite direction (swapping to **W** when holding **S** etc) when very near a wall the player object instantly blinks back as far as it can go in that opposite direction.

What should happen is the object should start to decelerate before inevitably hitting the wall it's careening towards, which is what happens when doing the same thing in reverse; ie moving rapidly along the y-axis in the -negative direction by holding **W** and then switching to **S** right before it hits the wall.

I don't know for sure but I'm pretty certain it's happening when the object is travelling towards the wall fast enough in a +positive direction, that it doesn't have enough time to slow down to a stop before hitting the wall by adding force in the opposite direction.

Here is a [short clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSoywqb6phU) of the incorrect behavior

And here is a [short clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8Mxibg0MDU) of the correct behavior working in the other direction.

And here is the simple Step script:

```cpp
// determine which input keys are being pressed and 
// increment/decrement vspd and hspd respectively
if (vspd < 0 || keyboard_check(ord('W'))){
    if place_meeting(x, y+vspd, block_obj)
    {
        // pixel-perfect collision resolution
        while(!place_meeting(x, y-1, block_obj))
        {
            y -= 1;
        }
        vspd = 0;
    }
    else if keyboard_check(ord('W'))
    {
        if(!place_meeting(x, y-1, block_obj))
            vspd -= 2;
    }
    else
    {
        if(vspd < -2) 
        {
            vspd += 1;
        }
        else
        { 
            vspd = 0;
        }
    }
} 
if (vspd > 0 || keyboard_check(ord('S'))){
    if place_meeting(x, y+vspd, block_obj)
    {
        // pixel-perfect collision resolution
        while(!place_meeting(x, y+1, block_obj))
        {
            y += 1;
        }
        vspd = 0;
    }
    else if keyboard_check(ord('S'))
    {
        if(!place_meeting(x, y+1, block_obj))
            vspd += 2;
    }
    else
    {
        if(vspd > 2)
        {
            vspd -= 1;
        }
        else
        {
            vspd = 0;
        }
    }
}

if (hspd < 0 || keyboard_check(ord('A'))){
    if place_meeting(x+hspd, y, block_obj)
    {
        // pixel-perfect collision resolution
        while(!place_meeting(x-1, y, block_obj))
        {
            x -= 1;
        }
        hspd = 0;
    }
    else if keyboard_check(ord('A'))
    {
        if(!place_meeting(x-1, y, block_obj))
            hspd -= 2;
    }
    else
    {
        if(hspd < -2) 
        {
            hspd += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            hspd = 0;
        }
    }
}
if (hspd > 0 || keyboard_check(ord('D'))){
    if place_meeting(x+hspd, y, block_obj)
    {
        // pixel-perfect collision resolution
        while(!place_meeting(x+1, y, block_obj))
        {
            x += 1;
        }
        hspd = 0;
    }
    else if keyboard_check(ord('D'))
    {
        if(!place_meeting(x+1, y, block_obj))
            hspd += 2;
    }
    else
    {
        if(hspd > 2)
        {
            hspd -= 1;
        }
        else
        {
            hspd = 0;
        }
    }
}

x += hspd;
y += vspd;
```

I can't seem to find the part of my Step code that's causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If I was doing this I would make each control separate from each other, by using else if statements. Pseudo-code e.g:

```
if (w) {
//code
} else if (a) {
//code
} else if (s) {
//code
} else if (d) {
//code
}
```

This should prevent / help your issue because you can no longer provide acceleration in multiple directions at once, if that doesn't completely work it might be because you are incrementing the axis movement into the wall and when you change direction you are accelerating towards that direction you were just in because the collision check is no longer an issue as you have collision checks inside the key presses, when you hit a wall you should not allow acceleration for that reason, only bounce the player back.
I have a project from years ago that does what you are trying to do, ill try and find it it that doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: I actually found the issue, I needed to make a separate variable for each direction of momentum, vNegSpd vPosSpd etc so when checking for collisions I only use the variable for that direction. 

The problem was that when I was say holding "D" and vspd was super high and I swapped "A", the "A" branch would check for a collision using that same super high vspd and would trigger the "snap to nearest wall" solution, snapping it all the way back to the other side of the screen.

Comment: Though breaking the inputs up could be a useful addition regardless. Though I would probably only break it into two (WA and SD) since I want to support diagonal movement.